# Twitter bootstrap rails - cannot find generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I added the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem and did bundle install. Then I went to do:

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```

This doesn't seem to work and says it cannot find the generator.

```
Could not find generator bootstrap:install.
```

I'm on rails 3.1. Why isn't this working?

EDIT: Hey not sure if you wanted the entire gemfile, but here it is:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'sorcery'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem "pg", :group => :production
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'acts_as_api'
gem 'taps'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

group :development do
  # To use debugger
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
end

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

and gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.1.0, 3.0.7, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
actionpack (3.1.0, 3.0.7, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
activeadmin (0.3.2)
activemodel (3.1.0, 3.0.7, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
activerecord (3.1.0, 3.0.7, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.0)
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.2.0)
activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (1.2.0)
activeresource (3.1.0, 3.0.7, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
activesupport (3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.7, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
acts_as_api (0.3.11)
addressable (2.2.6)
annotate-models (1.0.4)
ansi (1.4.1, 1.3.0)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (2.2.1, 2.0.9, 1.0.1)
autotest (4.3.2)
autotest-fsevent (0.2.4)
autotest-growl (0.2.9)
autotest-rails-pure (4.1.0)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.12)
chronic (0.6.4)
cocaine (0.2.0)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.3, 1.1.2)
columnize (0.3.5, 0.3.4)
commonjs (0.2.0)
cucumber (1.1.0)
daemons (1.1.3)
devise (1.4.8)
diff-lcs (1.1.3, 1.1.2)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
execjs (1.2.9)
factory_girl (1.3.3)
factory_girl_rails (1.0)
faker (0.3.1)
faraday (0.7.5, 0.6.1)
fastercsv (1.5.4)
formtastic (1.2.4)
gherkin (2.5.2)
gravatar_image_tag (0.1.0)
has_scope (0.5.1)
heroku (2.15.1, 2.8.5)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0, 0.4.2)
inherited_resources (1.2.2)
jdbc-mysql (5.1.13)
jdbc-sqlite3 (3.7.2)
jquery-rails (1.0.19, 1.0.18, 1.0.16)
json (1.6.3, 1.6.1)
kaminari (0.12.4)
launchy (2.0.5)
less (2.0.8)
less-rails (2.0.1)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-darwin-10)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
log4r (1.1.9)
macaddr (1.4.0)
mail (2.3.0, 2.2.19)
meta_search (1.1.1, 1.1.0.pre, 0.9.8)
mime-types (1.17.2, 1.16)
multi_json (1.0.4, 1.0.3)
multi_xml (0.4.1)
multipart-post (1.1.4, 1.1.3)
net-ldap (0.2.2)
nokogiri (1.5.0, 1.4.4)
oa-basic (0.3.0)
oa-core (0.3.0)
oa-enterprise (0.3.0)
oa-more (0.3.0)
oa-oauth (0.3.0)
oa-openid (0.3.0)
oauth (0.4.5)
oauth-plugin (0.4.0.pre7)
oauth2 (0.5.1, 0.4.1)
omniauth (0.3.0)
orm_adapter (0.0.5)
paperclip (2.4.4)
pg (0.11.0)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1)
pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.3)
rack (1.3.5, 1.3.4, 1.2.4, 1.2.2)
rack-cache (1.0.3)
rack-mount (0.8.3, 0.6.14)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7)
rails (3.1.0, 3.0.7, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
railties (3.1.0, 3.0.7, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.11, 3.10)
responders (0.6.4)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rspec (2.6.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-core (2.6.4, 2.0.1)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-rails (2.6.1.beta1, 2.0.1)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubygems-update (1.7.2)
rubyntlm (0.1.1)
rubyzip (0.9.5, 0.9.4)
sass (3.1.11, 3.1.10)
sass-rails (3.1.5, 3.1.4, 3.1.0)
sequel (3.20.0)
sinatra (1.0)
sorcery (0.7.5)
spork (0.8.4)
sprockets (2.0.3, 2.0.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.4, 1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3, 1.2.5)
sys-uname (0.8.6, 0.8.5)
systemu (2.2.0)
taps (0.3.23)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7, 1.0.6)
therubyracer (0.9.9)
thin (1.2.11)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10, 1.4.9)
turn (0.8.3)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (1.4.0)
tzinfo (0.3.31, 0.3.30, 0.3.27)
uglifier (1.1.0, 1.0.3)
uuid (2.3.4)
warden (1.0.6)
webrat (0.7.1)
will_paginate (3.0.2, 3.0.pre2)
XMLCanonicalizer (1.0.1)
```

Comment: That looks correct. Can you provide a copy of your `Gemfile` and the output of `gem list`?

Comment: What is the list of generators you get when you type in "rails g"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your gem file, I think you need to specify a version of the bootstrap gem, specifically v1.3.0 or before: https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails/versions/1.3.0

Check the dependencies for that vs. the current version, 1.4.1. Alternately, upgrade to rails 3.1.1.

Comment: Tried that. Got a different error at least: `method_missing': undefined method `less' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000001029dd048> (NoMethodError)

and a bunch of other stuff

Comment: I upgraded to rails 3.1.1 and that seemed to do the trick. thank you

Comment: Gotta love the bleeding edge. :D

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

Try running `rails g bootstrap:install` with your rails server off. That seems to have done the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1 (Ubuntu 11.10) and hadn't find any problem. The steps I've followed to try to reproduce your problem are:

```
rails new tb_example
cd tb_example
gedit Gemfile
```

Include the following line in Gemfile

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

And then install bundle and install bootstrap

```
bundle install
rails g bootstrap:install
```

Everything worked properly.

If you want to try my example project just tell me and I will find out how to send it to you so you can execute the last step "rails g bootstrap:install" and see if it works or not

Comment: I just created a new rails project, added the gem to the gemfile, and ran rails g bootstrap:install and the same error appeared. Now I'm very confused.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot reproduce your problem. Maybe you could try to execute `bundle update` and then `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed in 2.0.

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Comment: Is it only fixed in the main branch? I'm using 2.0.4 of the 'static' branch (I'm on windows) and I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Edit the gemfile by opening: "nano gemfile"

2.) Update twitter-bootstrap-rails by adding: gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", "~> 1.3.0" -where "~> 1.3.0" reflects the newest version.

-The newest version can be found at the bottom of [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails/versions/1.3.0) page.

3.) Run "bundle install"